# There is no Ubuntu One pairing record

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one

I just update to Ubuntu 11.04
And then i login to my UbuntuOne account via the ubuntuone client.
Sync works, but I says this error 'There is no Ubuntu One pairing record.'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try the following command from the terminal while ubuntuone-preferences window is open (all in one line, quotes should be included):

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=com.ubuntu.sso /credentials com.ubuntu.sso.ApplicationCredentials.login_to_get_credentials "string:Ubuntu One" "string:Workaround for LP:657850" int64:0
```

Please let us know if this works.

Comment: Ok. It says 'method return sender=:1.1426 -> dest=:1.1425 reply_serial=2' after running the command. 
but it stile says 'There is no Ubuntu One pairing record'.
On my desktop there not a error...

Comment: I just check my laptop again and now the red error i gone!! So thank ;)